# How to update the progress bar through Backgroundworker in C#?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a Backgrounder worker which generates the Excel file through the C# function `GenerateExcel()`. Within the GenerateExcel() function, I am using the progressbar to update the status. However, it is throwing an exception, that I cannot modify the GUI control. 
Any idea what could be the error in the code ?

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    GenerateExcel(FileName, 1);
});

backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Thanks

Comment: Managed to find background worker. Failed to find usage examples. It is RIGHT HERE on the official class documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx With 1.4k rep you should know better. This question is pollution. SO even suggests similar questions when you type the question title. Laziness.

Comment: I've just noticed that your profile says "What I don't like : When people respond with a RTFM when I ask a question." HAH. Welcome to programming.

Comment: @Gusdor, I am sorry,  I was trying so much to implement as suggested but I could not get it working. I was little restless you know. Now I have got it working and so Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress event. Then update the progress bar in that method.

```
BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress += new ReportProgressEventHandler()....
```

(Syntax is probably incorrect, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are getting - System.InvalidOperationException – Cross-thread operation not valid - Exception - This post might help you - http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/system_invalidoperationexception_cross_thread_operation_not_valid/

Answer (score 0):

You need to control the Backgroundworker event `ProgressChanged` and, inside the  main method, instead of changing the progressbar, use this:

```
BW1.ReportProgress(iProg)
```

And in your event, modify the Progressbar retriving the value in the `ProgressChangedEventArgs`:

```
ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
```