# how to show the progress bar while loading the crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

i am working on windows form application...i have a crystal report...for showing crystal report in button click event i given code like this:

```
SqlCommand cmdrslt = new SqlCommand("rptdeptwisevisitor", con.connect);
cmdrslt.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdrslt.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = frmdateval;
cmdrslt.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = Todateval;
SqlParameter tvp1 = cmdrslt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", DepTable);
tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.Dept";
da.SelectCommand = cmdrslt;
da.Fill(ds);
DeptWiseRpt rpt = new DeptWiseRpt();
if ((ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0)) {
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0));
    rpt.SetParameterValue("frmd", setparmstartd);
    rpt.SetParameterValue("tod", setparmendd);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;

}
```

this is taking time to load the data..so i want to put a progress bar on this form..how could I put it?
any help is very appreciable...

Comment: You can use a backgroundworker for this. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470927/c-sharp-winform-progressbar-and-backgroundworker) question for further information.

Comment: but i want to show progress bar..while loading the records..

Comment: Put all your code that takes a long time into the BackgroundWorker.DoWork method (you can also use Tasks).

Comment: sir could you pls show one example?

Comment: Using the search "c# backgroundworker progressbar site:stackoverflow.com" provides you with these results:
[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874122/running-a-method-in-backgroundworker-and-showing-progressbar)
[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465318/how-to-update-the-progress-bar-through-backgroundworker-in-c)
[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974213/c-updating-a-progress-bar-using-background-worker-from-a-different-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading report is a single operation (two at most: query and displaying the viewer), so that you can't split it do display progress accurately. You could display *progressless* bar or use animated image like this one:

[image]

That operation has to run in parallel to UI thread (use Thread, Task or BackgroundWorker), otherwise your progress (progressbar or image) will not get updated even once. For the time of loading you should not display report viewer itself (make it invisible or size 1x1). Once loading is completed: hide progress and display viewer.

Some code:

```
// hide viewer, show progress
CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = false;
pictureBoxProgress.Visible = true;
// start thread
(new Thread(() => {

    // your code
    SqlCommand cmdrslt = new SqlCommand("rptdeptwisevisitor", con.connect);
    cmdrslt.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdrslt.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = frmdateval;
    cmdrslt.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = Todateval;
    SqlParameter tvp1 = cmdrslt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", DepTable);
    tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.Dept";
    da.SelectCommand = cmdrslt;
    da.Fill(ds);
    DeptWiseRpt rpt = new DeptWiseRpt();
    if ((ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0)) {
        rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0));
        rpt.SetParameterValue("frmd", setparmstartd);
        rpt.SetParameterValue("tod", setparmendd);
        // controls operations require invoke
        BeginInvoke(() => {
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
            pictureBoxProgress.Visible = false;
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        });
    }
})).Start();
```

Comment: how i can give your animated image and what all are the changes i have to make in code?

Comment: Is not mine image. Make own, buy or find a free one. Use `PictureBox` to display it in winforms. See edit for code.

Comment: I have explained a necessary of using `Thread` already: you do not block UI thread while preparing data (query, setting up `DeptWiseRpt`). I am not sure how do deal if setting `ReportSource` itself is a bottleneck, perhaps crystal report has some options to *preload* (pre-render data). Here I can't help you. And about animated picture, search for "gif", there are plenty of gif-editors or converters (from avi to example). Or just find one in [internet](https://www.google.de/search?q=progress&tbas=0&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:i,itp:animated).

Comment: if i download jpg image..to which format i have to convert..to get as like your image(animated)

Comment: [Gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format). And you need multiple jpg's to make single gif. Perhaps you should try to download gif as a gif?

Comment: but i havent see any gif image like you given above